# Objective-C to C++ string conversion causing memory leak

Tags: c++, string, memory-leaks, nsstring

I'm making a call to a controller string datamember and using the `UTF8String` method to convert the NSString object into a C++ string object and this is causing me a memory leak. The call is made inside the core audio `RenderTone` function and looks like this:

```
InstrumentGridViewController *viewController = (InstrumentGridViewController *)inRefCon;
string cppTrackName = [viewController->trackName UTF8String];
```

The code is located in a for loop though and it's causing quite a memory leak. Any ideas why? I have to make the conversion because I'm doing a c++ function call with the `cppTrackName` variable. I also tried this: `string cppTrackName = "synthTrack #1";` and this works fine without causing any leaks but obviously I really need to read the value from my controller.

This is the error in console (constantly repeated):

```
objc[6352]: Object 0x68c3b60 of class __NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
```

Comment: Maybe I don't get something, but why are you using dereference operator instead of dot operator to obtain trackName?

Comment: `trackName` is a pointer and `->` is what is used for those kind of datamembers, no?

Comment: I would never use construct like this, that's why I asked. Why not to have trackName as `@synthesize`-d `@property` and then use dot notation like `[viewController.trackName UTF8String]`? And also, are you using ARC?

Comment: Not using ARC. You're right I should synthesize the property. I didn't think of doing it because it's barely used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Now that I have seen the message:

The implementation of `-[NSString UTF8String]` is free to assume an autorelease pool exists on the thread where the message is made.

Your audio callback is being called from a secondary (render) thread. Evidently, no autorelease pool exists on this thread at the time you message the string, thus the "No autorelease pool" console message.

Under typical circumstances, you would create an autorelease pool explicitly. **However**, this is the render thread. If it is a realtime audio  thread, you should not be locking (incl. heap allocations) or even using objc messaging (because it can lock, and objc messaging makes no guarantee about the maximum time a message send takes). ObjC APIs have (virtually) no place in realtime audio render contexts.

Comment: From the reference: "The returned C string is automatically freed just as a returned object would be released; you should copy the C string if it needs to store it outside of the autorelease context in which the C string is created." This might imply the autorelease pool isn't working properly as you suggest.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "these locks"? I have updated my post with the error code, it does indeed mention the pool but does that mean I should create one inside the `RenderTone` function and clear it? I'm not sure what else you mean by what and how, Instruments tool in xcode only says what object is leaking and that is the string..

Comment: @Sled rewritten since you added the message. can clarify if all'd not clear.

Comment: This means my RenderTone is written badly. The reason I'm doing this is because my app needs to be able to play different kinds of objects (`Song` and `Note`) I make the difference between the two inside the Render function and run the code accordingly to the type of playback. I don't know how to make the difference otherwise. Do you have any suggestions? Is it possible to have multiple `RenderTone` implementations for example so I could just call the right one when necessary instead of doing checks inside the `RenderTone` function?

Comment: @Sled Well, if a note is part of a song, the song may just render the notes. Otherwise, I would likely separate the implementations -- that is, Song and Note would have separate render implementations.

Comment: But is that possible though, overwriting RenderTone twice?

Comment: @Sled of course. each impl could pass separate callbacks, or you could make them polymorphic. it really depends on your program's structure and how you're willing to restructure it -- idk how you've implemented it thus far.